# Finding the coordinates of a node in D3.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg, translate

I am trying to get the x and y coordinates for nodes, and then use those coordinates to draw a straight line from one node to another if the edge has been specified to be straight:

```
 for (var x = 0; x < edges.length; x++) {
        // Check if the nodes exist for this edge
        var nodeFrom = nodes.filter(function(item:any) { return item.id === edges[x].from; });
        var nodeTo = nodes.filter(function(item:any) { return item.id === edges[x].to; });
        var currentStyle;
        var currentArrowheadStyle;

         if (edges[x].shape === "straight") {
                    edges[x].shape = svg.selectAll("g.edgePath").data(edges).enter().append("line");
                }
```

My node object looks like this:

```
 { id: 1, shape: "ellipse", label: "Start"},
 { id: 2, shape: "rect", label: "Square"},
 { id: 3, shape: "diamond", label: "Split (A)", class: "completed"},
 { id: 4, shape: "rect", label: "Square (A)", class: "in-progress"},
 { id: 5, shape: "rect",label: "Square (A)"},
 { id: 6, shape: "rect", label: "Square (A)"},
```

My edges look like this:

```
 { from: 5, to: 7, type: "vee", dashed: false },
 { from: 6, to: 7, type: "vee", dashed: false },
 { from: 3, to: 6, type: "vee", dashed: false, shape: "straight"},
 { from: 4, to: 7, type: "vee", dashed: false },
```

How do I then connect the the nodes with a straight line edge, identified by the shape property in the edges?

Thanks

Comment: Which d3 layout are you using? force? Is objects in nodes array have x and y positions?

Comment: Hi Gilsha, I'm using a library on top of d3 called dagre-d3, so there is not force or tree layout specified. Is there a way for me to get coordinates of each node with out having to use a layout? Or how can I use the force layout to get the coordinates from the data above? Thanks